# React - Calling a function through another component

Tags: reactjs

i've read a bunch of similar solution to this question, but nothing seems to work for me.
So what i'm trying to do is simply calling a function, but i want to call it from one component when the function is located in another component. I just can't get it to work.

So this is the Search component, where i render my search results of games, with an onClick function that would later add the games in another list called favorites.

```
class Search extends React.Component {
...

renderSearchResults = () => {
    const { results } = this.state;
    if ( Object.keys(results).length && results.length) {
        return (
            <div className="results-container">
                {results.map(result => {
                    return(
                        <li onClick={((e) => this.clickToSave(e, result))} key={result.id} className="game"><span className="title">{result.name}</span><img src={result.background_image}/></li>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
};

...
}
export default Search
```

And the Favorites component where i want the function "clickToSave" to be located.

```
class SaveToFavorites extends React.Component {
...

clickToSave = (e, result) => {
    if(this.state.favorites.indexOf(result) < 0){
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            favorites: [...prevState.favorites, result],
            favoritesError: ''
        }))
    }
    else(
        this.setState({
            favoritesError: 'you have already added this game',
        })
    )
};

...
}
export default SaveToFavorites
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You'll have to give a bit more context than that. How are the two components related? Can one pass the function to the other? Do they share a parent that could orchestrate this? Do you have any kind of state container (e.g. Redux) to connect the components to? Etc. What did you try, and what does *"just can't get it to work"* actually mean?

Comment: Sorry, i'm very new to react. I do have an node.js installation. I don't use Redux. They are both child components to my main App.js component.

I have been trying solutions i've read on here to refer to the other component with something like this:
<SaveToFavorites clickToSave={this.clickToSave(e, result)} />
and in many other ways.

Comment: Give a [mre], then.